# Adding several elements to a list from text file

Tags: python

```
try:
    fileName = 'C:\pro.txt'
    textF = open(fileName, 'r')
    lines = textF.read()
except IOError:
    print("Not found")

paragraph = lines.split('\n\n')
paragraph[:] = (words for words in paragraph if words != '\t')

for w in paragraph:
    if w.isupper() == True:
        paragraphUpper = []
        paragraphUpper.extend([w])
        print(paragraphUpper[0])
```

Hey everyone so I have a little problem about adding several elements to a list from text file. In this code I have managed to find all uppercase lines, yet when I try to add them one by one to my list as new elements, it doesn't happen. It adds the whole as the first element of the array. How can I manage to add the lines as new elements?

I've tried splitting w by splitlines. I've tried splitting the paragraph only one line instead of two newlines, but it still adds only one element to the list.

Here is a snippet of the text file:

> I
>
> LAY OF THE LAND
>
> There is a vast field of fascinating human interest, lying only just
>   outside our doors, which as yet has been but little explored. It is
>   the Field of Animal Intelligence.
>
> Of all the kinds of interest attaching to the study of the world's
>   wild animals, there are none that surpass the study of their minds,
>   their morals, and the acts that they perform as the results of their
>   mental processes.
>
> In these pages, the term "animal" is not used in its most common and
>   most restricted sense. It is intended to apply not only to quadrupeds,
>   but also to all the vertebrate forms,--mammals, birds, reptiles,
>   amphibians and fishes.
>
> II
>
> WILD ANIMAL TEMPERAMENT & INDIVIDUALITY
>
> What I am trying to do here is, find the uppercase lines, and put them
>   all in an array. Then, using the index method, I will find the first
>   and last paragraphs of each section by comparing the indexes of these
>   elements of this array I created.

Comment: Can we see a snippet of this text file?

Comment: Also it will be beneficial for you to use `textF.readlines()` instead of `textF.read()`

Comment: I've made some edits.

Comment: You want to keep these roman numerals inside with the headlines ?

Comment: After finding the indexes of my titles, I am planning to put them into another array and then arrange the last line by my calculations. In my calculations I have seen a pattern that including the roman numerals the last paragraph of the section is always array[-3]. The only problem in this, is I cannot split the lines into elements and it adds the whole into one element.

Comment: @yechta please see my answer. It should be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily use one list comprehensions for this problem. If you switch to `readlines()`, the `paragraph[:] = ...` line is useless. This will suit your needs:

```
try:
    fileName = 'C:\pro.txt'
    textF = open(fileName, 'r')
    paragraph = textF.readlines()
except IOError:
    print("Not found")

paragraphUpper = [w.strip() for w in paragraph if w.isupper()]
print paragraphUpper
```

Comment: This absolutely suits my needs! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, use `f.readlines()`; that splits the file into a list of lines.

There are quite a few other strange things in your code:

- There is no need to do `paragraph[:]` for the list comprehension; just reassign the variable with `paragraph = ...`.
- Don't compare with `True`, just do `if w.isupper():`
- You redefine `paragraphUpper` as a new empty list each time through your loop; so it will only ever contain one element. You need to create it once, before the for statement.
- Don't wrap a single item in a list to do `paragraphUpper.extend([w])`, just do `paragraphUpper.append(w)`.
- Use consistent indentation; the first few lines have an indent of 4 spaces, the loops at the end have an indent of just 1. The Python standard is 4.

Answer (score 0):

To get uppercase lines, use this:

```
 try:
     fileName = 'C:\pro.txt'
     textF = open(fileName,'r')
     lines = textF.readlines()
  except IOError:
     print("Not found")
 UpperLines = []
 for line in lines:
     if line.isupper():
         UpperLines.append(line)
         print(line)
```